# Magento add Customer Email to adminhtml order grid (Mage 1.8)

Tags: orders, adminhtml, overrides, core

I am trying to add the Customer Email to our adminhtml order grid. We are overriding the code in Mage/core in this file: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

In PrepareColumns we add

```
$this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Email'),
    'width'     => '100px',
    'index'     => 'customer_email',
    'type'        => 'text',

));
```

And in _prepareCollection we added this

```
$customer_entity = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_entity');
        $collection->getSelect()
               ->join(
               $customer_entity,
               'main_table.customer_id = '.$customer_entity.'.entity_id', array('customer_email' => 'email'));
```

The good news is, that it does add the email column

**My question**: Now the only problem is that when we enter an order id, or sku as filter that the result is the Magento error page .... So something is still going wrong here

What are we forgetting? Or what is the best code for Magento 1.8 to add the Email address in the order grid?

Comment: can you please look in `var/report/error_id` and tell us what is the error? it might help us to solve issue easily.

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous";i:1;s:7011:"

Comment: This isn't an direct answer to your question, but if you are looking to add the customer email address to your shop, please take a look at https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really solved our problem and more!!!

https://github.com/mage-eag/mage-enhanced-admin-grids

This really improved our Magento ways of Working. Should be default.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy Grid.php  to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/`
Then append  `sales_flat_order table to collection`

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('customer_email'));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    };
```

And a addColumn to _prepareColumns()

```
 $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment method'),
    'index' => 'customer_email',
    'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order.customer_email',
    ));
```

More details can be find [`here`](http://bluehorse.in/blog/how-to-add-some-field-or-column--into-magento-order-grid-in-magento-or-customized-magento-order-grid.html).

Comment: HI. This is not working, we keep getting the error (after entering filter for example an order id) a:5:{i:0;s:104:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous";i:1;s:7011:"#0

Comment: Bottom line is: this code shows the email, but as an effect we cannnot filter

Comment: Addition of filter_index fixed the problem

Comment: plz up my answer

Comment: ? Addition of filter_index fixed the problem

Comment: For the record - I had to add the filter_index option to (almost) every column on that grid after joining the flat order table. The issue is the columns exist in both the main_table that the grid uses, and the flat order table, so the system doesn't know which to use when filtering. I can't help think there must be a better solution than this that avoids that issue.

Answer (score 0):

**our observer.php file**

```
<?php

class Excellence_Ordergrid_Model_Observer {

    /**
     *  Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * call the function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore handles our event to the observer
     */
    public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /** @var $block Mage_Core_Block_Abstract */
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if ($block->getId() == 'sales_order_grid') {
            $block->addColumnAfter('email', array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Email'),
                    'width' => '110px',
                    'index' => 'email',
                    'type' => 'text',
                ), 'full_address');
        }
    }

    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();  
        $select->joinLeft(array('mail' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_address')), 'mail.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('email' => 'email'));
    }
```